# как вывести изменения в bdgrid delphi

Tags: база-данных, delphi, delphi-7, access

Пишу программу на делфи с бд. Вывод содержимого бд нормальный. хочу сделать вывод определенных записей, т.е выборка. но суть в том, что она не получается сам запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поясните пожалуйста, что здесь не так. использую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сама форма выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  year: integer;
begin
  year := StrToInt(Edit1.Text); 
  ...
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE [Год устройства на работу] > ' + IntToStr(year));
```

так как `[Год устройства на работу]` - числовое поле, кавычки вокруг значения не нужны (тем более, что закрывающая кавычка была пропущена).

Еще. Если Вам действительно надо выбрать работников со стажем больше указанного, то знак сравнения надо поменять на `<` - `меньше`.